# Simple JQuery working in some areas, not in others

Tags: javascript, jquery

After I added a slideshow to the site I am working on, some web components that use Jquery stopped working. However the newly added slideshow that also uses JQuery works as expected.

After some debugging, I found out exactly what JQuery is working and what isn't from the code below. I added a comment to my code to indicate that point.

I am importing my jquery library in the header and the code below is the last code before the closing `<body>` tag.

```
<!--SLIDESHOW-->    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {};

        if (document.location.search) {
            var array = document.location.search.split('=');
            var param = array[0].replace('?', '');
            var value = array[1];

            if (param == 'animation') {
                options.animation = value;
            }
            else if (param == 'type_navigation') {
                if (value == 'dots_preview') {
                    $('.border_box').css({'marginBottom': '40px'});
                    options['dots'] = true;
                    options['preview'] = true;
                }
                else {
                    options[value] = true;
                    if (value == 'dots') $('.border_box').css({'marginBottom': '40px'});
                }
            }
        }

        $('.box_skitter_large').skitter(options);

        // Highlight
        $('pre.code').highlight({source:1, zebra:1, indent:'space', list:'ol'});

           //**** everything above works, everything below this point does not! ****/
        $(".expandButton").click(function(ev){
            $(ev.target).closest(".company-container").find(".expand").css("height", "140px");
            $(ev.target).closest(".company-container").find(".expand").toggle("fast");
        });         
        $(".emailLink, .email-popup").click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".expand").css("height", "140px");
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".email-popup").show("fast");
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".phone-popup").hide();
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".address-popup").hide();
        });
        $(".addressLink, .address-popup").click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".expand").css("height", "550px");
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".address-popup").show("fast");
            var address = $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".address").html(); //get address text
            if(!($(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".map").length)){ //check if it was loaded
                $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".address-popup").html('<iframe class="map" style="margin-top:45px;" width="575" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q='+ address +' &amp;aq=&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear='+address+'&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>'); 
            }
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".email-popup").hide();
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".phone-popup").hide();
        });
        $(".phoneLink, .phone-popup").click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".expand").css("height", "140px");
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".phone-popup").show("fast");
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".email-popup").hide();
            $(e.target).closest(".company-container").find(".address-popup").hide();
        });
        $(document).click(function(e) {
             if (!(e.target.class === "email-popup" || e.target.class === "phone-popup")) {
                $(".email-popup, .phone-popup, .address-popup").hide("fast");                
             }
             $(".expand").css("height","140px");
        });     
        $(".tagKeyword").hover(function(){
            $(this).css("background-color","#fff");
            $(this).css("color","blue");
            $(this).css("box-shadow","none");
        });
        $(".tagKeyword").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css("background-color","#eee");
            $(this).css("color","#556");
            $(this).css("box-shadow","1px 1px 2px #ccc");
        });
        $(".search-container").hover(function(){
            $(".search-container").css("background","url(./images/menu/menu-middle.png)");
        });
        $(".searchfield").Watermark("search");
    });
```

Comment: I hate to sound annoying but, utilizing console.log, triple check where it's breaking. Then just zone in on that area and find out if that code works by itself. Let us know what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$(".expandButton").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".company-container").find(".expand").css("height", "140px");
    $(this).closest(".company-container").find(".expand").toggle("fast");
});
```

This may not help at all, but I didn't see the need for `ev` here and to instead use `this`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Gave that a try, it didnt help. I have been using ev for months. I don't see why that would cause a problem. I appreciate your input though.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to double check  ev variable:

```
ev = ev || window.event
```